# Map the ObjectId Pointer to a Collection in Parse during REST / CSV data upload?

Tags: android, ios, rest, mobile, parse-platform

We are using [Parse](http://parse.com/) as the backend for an Android & Iphone mobile application. The database has two collections one for Stores and the other for Products. One Store can have multiple products, however, one product can only belong to one store.

For this use case, we have used a pointer column in the Product collection which points to the objectId for the store. Now, we want to bulk upload products & stores to the database using either the CSV imports or the REST API.

How can we map the products in the database to the corresponding store's objectId automatically during upload? We have a unique identifiers for stores, products & their mapping in the data we are uploading.